# Difference between it and there

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

There is this situation that:

A boy saw a silhouette in the moonlight. Not sure what it actually was, he thought "was it/there really a Martian in his room tonight?"

(Actually the boy is scared of aliens and before this above mentioned scene his sister scared him saying that a Martian would come to his room soon)

How would "it" and "there" change the meaning of the sentence?

Comment: Do ***not*** put quote marks around the text representing what the boy thought unless that text is "verbatim". In your example, that would be *...he thought "**Is there really a Martian in my room tonight**?"* And if you're *not* going to write his thoughts down verbatim like that, ***thought*** probably isn't the right verb anyway - it would be better to use a different verb, such as *...he **wondered if** there **was** really a Martian in his room **that night***.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Was it really a Martian?" means 'was the apparition really a Martian (or something else)?' ("in his room" would be a bit superfluous here.)

"Was there a Martian in his room?" means 'was a Martian present in the room?"

NB If you are directly quoting his thoughts, they would be "**Is** there a Martian in **my** room?"